# How to make the following code produces the current month plus the 12 previous months?

Tags: javascript, date

The following code takes the current month of this year and formats it in calendar fashion:

```
let curYear = 2017
let curMonth = 11
let result = []
let firstDayOfMonth = new Date(curYear, curMonth, 1)
let lastDayOfMonth = new Date(curYear, curMonth, getLastDayOfMonth(curMonth))

result.unshift(firstDayOfMonth)
for (let d = prevDate(firstDayOfMonth); d.getDay() !== 6; d = this.prevDate(d)) {
  result.unshift(d)
}
for (let d = nextDate(firstDayOfMonth); d <= lastDayOfMonth; d = nextDate(d)) {
  result.push(d)
}
for (let d = nextDate(lastDayOfMonth); d.getDay() !== 0; d = nextDate(d)) {
  result.push(d)
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))

function nextDate (d) {
  let result = new Date(d.valueOf())
  result.setDate(d.getDate() + 1)
  return result
}

function prevDate (d) {
  let result = new Date(d.valueOf())
  result.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)
  return result
}

function getLastDayOfMonth (m) {
  let result = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
  if (leapYear) {
    result[1] = 29
  }
  return result[m]
}

function leapYear () {
  if (curYear % 100 === 0) {
    return curYear % 400 === 0
  } else {
    return curYear % 4 === 0
  }
}
```

Output:

> ["2017-11-25T16:00:00.000Z","2017-11-26T16:00:00.000Z","2017-11-27T16:00:00.000Z","2017-11-28T16:00:00.000Z","2017-11-29T16:00:00.000Z","2017-11-30T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-01T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-02T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-03T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-04T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-05T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-06T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-07T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-08T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-09T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-10T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-11T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-12T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-13T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-14T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-15T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-16T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-17T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-18T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-19T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-20T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-21T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-22T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-23T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-24T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-25T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-26T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-27T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-28T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-29T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-30T16:00:00.000Z","2017-12-31T16:00:00.000Z","2018-01-01T16:00:00.000Z","2018-01-02T16:00:00.000Z","2018-01-03T16:00:00.000Z","2018-01-04T16:00:00.000Z","2018-01-05T16:00:00.000Z"]

How to modify this function so it returns the current month plus the previous 12 months?

For example (read from right to left):

```
(and so on) ... 2017-10-05, ... 2017-11-05, ... 2017-12-05, ... , 2018-01-05]
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/alexcheninfo/pen/zpGMvz

Note: I also welcome Moment.js/Luxon alternatives

Comment: Have you thought of using some kind of library for more support? Like moment.js

Comment: You wrote all that code and you don't know how to do the easiest part?

Comment: What should the output look like?

Comment: @Adelin The original code isn't mine. I just modified it.

Comment: This is the same type of question a beginner asks: "do this project for me please". What have you tried? What problems are you encountering? Downvoting

Comment: @Adelin Well, I did spend heck a lot of time writing the question and preparing the Codepen. I do have a failed attempt, but it's going to make the question longer. Should I include anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// use moment.js
let curDate = moment();    
let newDate = moment().add(12, 'month');
let dateValues = [];

while (newDate > curDate) {
   dateValues.push(curDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
   curDate.add(1,'month');
}
```

Comment: I think that only produces a string not an array containing the months?

Comment: @alex you need array of twelve months?

Comment: Yes I need the array.

Comment: @alex got it yup.

Comment: @alex check your answer now its completed